# Unregestering event handler registered in static method

Tags: c#, hyperlink, event-handling

I've registered an event handler in one of my static function and would like to know a good way to deregistered it, since i can't use the desconstructor to deregister.

My code:

```
public class LinkExecutor
{
    private static Hyperlink link;
    private static Hyperlink Link
    {
        get
        {
            if (link == null)
            {
                link = new Hyperlink() { TargetName = "_blank" };
                link.RequestNavigate += new System.Windows.Navigation.RequestNavigateEventHandler(Link_RequestNavigate);
            }
            return link;
        }
    }

    public static void ExecuteAdressLink(int partnerID)
    {
        string adrLink = "http://adress/?&pid=";
        this.link.NavigateUri = new Uri(adrLink + partnerID.ToString());
        this.link.DoClick();
    }

    private static void Link_RequestNavigate(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.RequestNavigateEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(e.Uri.ToString());
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
Actually i would like to find a way to deregister automatically without creating / calling extra function.

**EDIT2**
When the class is not anymore used, i would like to deregister but if i think about it, with the static function, it's not approriate.

Is it better to just create (with deregister) the Hyperlink everytime when function is called? Or should i just make the function non-static and use deconstructor?

Comment: are you asking about the syntax to de-reg?

Comment: **When** would you like to automatically deregister?

Answer (score 1):

You say that you want to remove the reference when the class isn't used anymore, but *the class is never not used anymore*, because it's static; it is in scope throughout the entire lifetime of the application, and there's no need to remove the handler when the entire application ends.

Answer (score 0):

to de-register the event you just do this:

```
private static void Deregister(){
    link.RequestNavigate -= new System.Windows.Navigation.RequestNavigateEventHandler(Link_RequestNavigate);
}
```